# The commutative property of multiplication in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby, I was messing around in the irb and found two code samples that should work the same but don't

```
"a" * 4     #this is "aaaa"
4 * "a"     #this is "String can't be coerced into a Fixnum"
```

Doesn't this violate the commutative property of multiplication?

Comment: The commutative property of multiplication is a mathematical principle. Ruby is a programming language. The `*` operator is not a multiplication sign, it's syntactic sugar for the `*` method of the String and Fixnum classes, respectively. It doesn't "violate" the commutative property because it's not bound by it, any more than the `print` method is bound by the principles of English grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does violate the commutative property, but that's not necessarily a problem, as the commutative property applies to the complex complex numbers in math. The reason `"a" * 4` is not commutative in Ruby, as in most programming languages, is because a given type defines how it handles operators. So you could override the `*` operator for the `String` and `Fixnum` class (but that's a VERY VERY bad idea in practice):

```
class String
    def *(other)
        if other.is_a?(Numeric)
            puts "The method was called on an instance of String"
        end
    end
end

class Fixnum
    def *(other)
        if other.is_a?(Numeric)
            puts "The method was called on an instance of Fixnum"
        end
    end
end
```

So if you were to call

```
"a" * 4
```

Then it would print `"The method was called on an instance of String"` because that is equivalent to `"a".*(4)`

But this:

```
4 * "a"
```

Would print `"The method was called on an instance of Fixnum"` because `4 * "a"` is equivalent to `4.*("a")`

[Here](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2010/04/operator-overloading.html) is a good article on operator overloading in Ruby.

Interesting side note: the commutative property actually doesn't apply to all numbers in math, the [Quaterions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) and the [Octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) both are not commutative.

**Edit**

If you wanted to, you could make the `*` operator commutative (but that would be a bad idea). You could then define `*` to swap the callee and the argument like such:

```
class Fixnum
    def *(other)
        other * self
    end
end
```

That way, when ever you have `4 * "a"` it would actually do this: `"a" * 4`. This would still work even if `String#*` was later redefined. [Monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls) can often be useful, but in this case it's a terrible idea, I don't recommend doing this, it's just a cool proof of concept.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is how all programming languages with operator overloading work (at least, all of them that I know). So it's not a Ruby-specific quirk. And +1 for a proper in-depth explanation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
"a" * 4 # repeat 'a' 4 times
4 * "a" # multiply 4 times the string 'a'
```

It's not multiplication unless two numbers are involved.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, everything is an object. `"a"` is an object of class `String`, whereas `4` is an object of class `Fixnum`. So even numbers are objects.

And objects can have methods.

`4` has a method called `*` that takes a number as an argument and multiplies 4 by that number. This method doesn't accept a string as an argument; it will unsuccessfully try to coerce the string to a number. (That's what explains your error message.)

`"a"` has a completely different method called `*` that takes a number as an argument. This method repeats the string multiple times.

Therefore:

```
4.*(4)    # =>16
"a".*(4)  # => "aaaa"
```

Ruby also lets you use a more succinct syntax for the `*` methods:

```
4 * 4     # =>16
"a" * 4   # => "aaaa"
```

But it's just a different way of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a combination of precedence an the fact that they are both objects. What you are effectively doing in the 2nd version is 4.*("a"). Calling method '*' with parameter "a" on the Fixnum instance with value 4. So the String "a" cannot be coerced.